# Two values of moment of inertia ($I$) at $x=l/4$ in rod, when calculated differently

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotation, moment-of-inertia

I'm using **parallel-axes theorem** in both the following methods to calculate $I$ of a rod about a point (say $P$) at $x=l/4$ from C, $\perp$ to the rod.

[image]

**Method 1:** We know, $I$ about the centre C, $\perp$ to it is $ ml^2/12$, then
$$ I_P = \frac{ml^2}{12} + m\bigg({\frac{l}{4}}\bigg)^2 $$

**Method 2:** We know, $I$ about an end, $\perp$ to it is $ml^2/3$, then
$$ I_P = \frac{ml^2}{3} + m\bigg({\frac{l}{4}}\bigg)^2 $$

Isn't this strange, or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parallel Axes theorem states that

$$I_{P}=I_{CM}+md^2$$

Here,$d$ is the perpendicular distance of point P from axis paaing through $CM$.

You have put in $I_{cm}=\frac{ml^2}{3}$ in 2nd case which is incorrect because $I_{cm}$ is same for both cases.

Answer (score 1):

In your method 2, $ml^2/3$ does not correspond to $I_\mathrm{CM}$.